# Hot to integrate Kiwi with Redmine?

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins, kiwi-tcms

We're using Kiwi TCMS, we're able to create test cases and bugs in Kiwi but we are not clear on how to integrate with our Redmine.

It would be great if someone can guide us on how to link both platforms, in order to track or update the bugs/test cases from each tool.

The Kiwi documentation is not very clear about it, please we need a clear step-by-step on how to integrate Redmine<>Kiwi TCMS

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> The Kiwi documentation is not very clear about it, please we need a clear step-by-step on how to integrate Redmine<>Kiwi TCMS

You have to be more precise than that. What exactly is not clear to you ? What is it that you are trying to achieve ?

From https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-external-bug-trackers:

- The extent of integration with 3rd party bug tracking systems is documented in https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.html#module-tcms.issuetracker aka scope definition for integration
- Important: Details on what each field means can be found at tcms.testcases.models.BugSystem. Integration details for supported bug trackers can be found at tcms.issuetracker.types! Please read these sections carefully before configuring integration with external bug tracking systems! Module names in the original documentation are links to other documentation pages which describe the meaning of each field and what values go into them.

Given all of this information if you are asking for help you need to ask a more specific question or describe a more specific scenario which isn't working for you. Otherwise nobody can help you.